# WMI call takes too much time when system Starts/ReStarts

Tags: c#, .net, performance, windows-services, wmi

I want to get the path of the Windows Service,

```
var managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Service where serviceName = MyService");
```

this code is written of the constructor of some other service...

everything works fine when system is UP and running but if i restart the system put the StopWatch class for this call and it shows that it shows that the service takes 35-45 seconds to start because of this call..

Any suggestions to improve the performance on system restart...

Comment: Have yo tried to use PowerShell instead?

Comment: I haven't used powershell..any specific advantage over WMI call...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Windows32_Services class doesn't exist, so assuming which you are using the [`Win32_Service`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class you can improve the performance only returning the properties which you want to use, in this case the `PathName`, so change your WQL sentence to

```
SELECT PathName FROM Win32_Service Where Name='MyService'
```

**UPDATE**

The observation made for [@Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon) is quite correct, since you know the name of thes service to retrieve, you can build the object path of the  Win32_Service which look like

```
Win32_Service.Name="ServiceName"
```

And then using the [`ManagementObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeteazb7.aspx) class you can retrieve the instance to the service in a fastest way.

Comment: Since you're filtering by `Name`, which a key property of the [Win32_Service class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418.aspx), it would be faster to just access the instance directly without doing the search: `string path = "Win32_Service.Name=\"MyService\""; ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(path); string pathName = (string) service.GetPropertyValue("PathName");`  But I think the author is saying that it takes a long time for WMI to initialize, not that the query is taking too long to execute.

Comment: Yes, but using a query you're having to access the `Name` property of each `Win32_Service` instance.  So, it's retrieving 25 properties of one instance vs. one property of all instances (on my 64-bit Windows 7 Professional laptop there are 188 services).  In a quick test of 1,000 iterations of each method of retrieving the `PathName` property of a service, constructing a `ManagementObject` by path takes less than 10 seconds, whereas using a `ManagementObjectSearcher` takes about two minutes.  Removing any `using` blocks and use of LINQ from the latter does get it down to about a minute.

Comment: @Bacon, I misunderstood your original comment about using the object path of the instance with the `ManagementObject` instead of `ManagementObjectSearcher`, your observation is quite correct, Also getting a `ManagementObject` directly is much better than  get a `ManagementObjectSearcher` and enum each instance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're retrieving the service by `Name`, which a key property of the [`Win32_Service class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418.aspx), try retrieving the instance directly instead of searching for it:

```
string GetMyServicePath()
{
    string path = "Win32_Service.Name=\"MyService\"";

    using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(path))
        return (string) service.GetPropertyValue("PathName");
}
```

Here's a quick benchmark I threw together to compare direct retrieval vs. searching:

```
private const int LoopIterations = 1000;

private const string ServiceClass = "Win32_Service";
private const string ServiceName = "MyService";
private const string ServiceProperty = "PathName";

private static readonly string ServicePath = string.Format("{0}.Name=\"{1}\"", ServiceClass, ServiceName);
private static readonly string ServiceQuery = string.Format(
    "SELECT {0} FROM {1} Where Name=\"{2}\"",
    ServiceProperty, ServiceClass, ServiceName
);
private static ManagementObjectSearcher ServiceSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ServiceQuery);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();

    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < LoopIterations; i++)
    {
        var servicePath = GetServicePathByKey();
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0:N0} iterations of GetServicePathByKey() took {1:N0} milliseconds",
        LoopIterations, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    );

    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < LoopIterations; i++)
    {
        var servicePath = GetServicePathFromExistingSearcher();
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0:N0} iterations of GetServicePathFromExistingSearcher() took {1:N0} milliseconds",
        LoopIterations, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    );

    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < LoopIterations; i++)
    {
        var servicePath = GetServicePathFromNewSearcher();
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0:N0} iterations of GetServicePathFromNewSearcher() took {1:N0} milliseconds",
        LoopIterations, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    );
}

static string GetServicePathByKey()
{
    using (var service = new ManagementObject(ServicePath))
        return (string) service.GetPropertyValue(ServiceProperty);
}

static string GetServicePathFromExistingSearcher()
{
    using (var results = ServiceSearcher.Get())
    using (var enumerator = results.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            throw new Exception();

        return (string) enumerator.Current.GetPropertyValue(ServiceProperty);
    }
}

static string GetServicePathFromNewSearcher()
{
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ServiceQuery))
    using (var results = searcher.Get())
    using (var enumerator = results.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            throw new Exception();

        return (string) enumerator.Current.GetPropertyValue(ServiceProperty);
    }
}
```

Enumerating the searcher results directly is about as fast as I could make it, marginally faster than using a `foreach` block and twice as fast as using `LINQ`.  On my 64-bit Windows 7 Professional system with the `ServiceName` constant set to `Power` I got these results:

```
1,000 iterations of GetServicePathByKey() took 8,263 milliseconds
1,000 iterations of GetServicePathFromExistingSearcher() took 64,265 milliseconds
1,000 iterations of GetServicePathFromNewSearcher() took 64,875 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is the "latency" of WMI that is bothering you, you don't have to use WMI to get a service's path, ie. executable name. You can also P/invoke [QueryServiceConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/queryserviceconfig.html