# WMI call performance

Tags: c#, wmi

I need to make a WMI call in the constructor of my service. But when I start/restart the system this call takes significant amount of time.

I am using the following code to get the path of the windows service....
Here I've used the `EnumerationOptions` to improve the query performance, now in order to use it I have to use the `ManagementScope` which is **"root\civm2"**, every time I've to use "root'civm2" as Management scope,

Earlier I was using `managementObjectCollection.Count` to know whether it contains any items or not, now to improve the performance I am using `managementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext`, will it help, I've commented the count related code.

Is there any better way to improve the performance of the same code...

```cs
EnumerationOptions options = new EnumerationOptions();
//   options.Rewindable = false; **// I HAVE TO COMMENT OUT THIS IN ORDER TO GET THE RESULTS....**
options.ReturnImmediately = true;

string query = string.Format("SELECT PathName FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '{0}'", "MyService");


ManagementScope ms12 = new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2");
ms12.Connect();


using (var managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{
    managementObjectSearcher.Scope = ms12;
    managementObjectSearcher.Options = options;

    var managementObjectCollection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();

    //if (managementObjectCollection.Count > 0)
    //{
        var managementObjectEnumerator = managementObjectCollection.GetEnumerator();

        if (managementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var invalidChars = new Regex(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "[{0}]", Regex.Escape(new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()))));
            var path = invalidChars.Replace(managementObjectEnumerator.Current.GetPropertyValue("PathName").ToString(), string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
    //}
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Else part...");
        }
}
```

**Am I using the scope and EnumerationOption in correct way??**
Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer to your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502879/wmi-call-takes-too-much-time-when-system-starts-restarts) suggest you can build the object path of the class and use the ManagementObject directly to improve the performance , now if you want to check if the ManagementObject return an instance you can use the private property `IsBound`.

```
string ServicePath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name=\"{0}\"", "MyService");
var WMiObject = new ManagementObject(ServicePath);
PropertyInfo PInfo = typeof(ManagementObject).GetProperty("IsBound", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if ((bool)PInfo.GetValue(WMiObject, null))
{
    string PathName = (string)WMiObject.GetPropertyValue("PathName");
    var invalidChars = new Regex(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "[{0}]", Regex.Escape(new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()))));
    var path = invalidChars.Replace(PathName, string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Else part...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in more recent versions of the .NET framework the binding happens as late as possible. At least this was the case for me when I was testing the existence of a specific shared folder.

Here is an update to @RRUZ 's solution which uses a try-catch instead of reflecting the IsBound internal property.

```
var servicePath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name=\"{0}\"", "MyService");
string pathName = null;
try
{
    var wmiObject = new ManagementObject(servicePath);
    pathName = (string)wmiObject.GetPropertyValue("PathName");
}
catch {}

if (pathName != null)
{
    var invalidChars = new Regex(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "[{0}]", Regex.Escape(new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()))));
    var path = invalidChars.Replace(pathName, string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Else part...");
}
```