# Is there a way to speed up the first connection phase of a WMI connection to a remote computer in C#?

Tags: c#, wmi

I have an application where I read some informations of remote machine-computers in our plant. Normaly the connection speed from my server to the machines is very fast. But when I make a WMI connection, just the connection part (scope.connect, not the query) takes 10-11 seconds . I have tried to several machines but the time is always 10-11 seconds. I know that WMI is not fast but I didn't expect such a long connection time. Is there a way to shorten this time? I know that something caan be adjusted in the options,but Idon't know how to proceed.

```
        public void WMI_Connect()
          {

            WMI_path = "\\\\" + TagService.IP_to_Connect + "\\root\\cimv2";
            
            System.Management.ConnectionOptions options = new    System.Management.ConnectionOptions();
            options.Username = username;
            options.Password = password;
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(WMI_path, options);
            scope.Connect();
          }
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520754/wmi-call-performance)

Comment: @PeterSmith OK, but my problem is not that the query takes long. Therefore I haven't added it tomy code. Just the scope.connect takes min 10 seconds,aftrwards the query isn't so slow.

Comment: No.  To establish the connection you need credentials and you network is slow in getting the credentials.  Blame the network, not your code.

Comment: @jdweng I didn't get you excactly I directly define the credentials (username and password, as the admin username and password on the remote PC) I mean this not fetched from anywhere. Why should this be slow?

Comment: I've seen it happen too many times.    Don't know if server are overloaded, priority of messages are low, or blocked by other messages.